# Install opencv for C++ on Mac m1 chip properly

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, opencv, apple-m1

I've tried to install openCV for C++ using this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KaTA-yK7dWA
and then try to set it up on Xcode using this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2FYm3GOonhk&t=1266s

But when I ran the code:

```
 #include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
 #include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
 #include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
 #include <iostream>

 using namespace cv;
 using namespace std;

 ///////////////// Webcam //////////////////////

 int main() {

   VideoCapture cap(1);
   Mat img;

   while (true) {

   cap.read(img);
   imshow("Image", img);
   waitKey(1);

  }
  return 0;
 }
```

I got the error:
ld: library not found for -lopencv_photo.4.5.5
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
don't know what to do, I'll be glad for help and guidance, it was much easier in python
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

As the linker says - it cannot find the library `lopencv_photo.4.5.5` to link against your program.

In Xcode the easiest option is to append the flag `-lopencv_photo` to `Other Linker Flags` in your Project Preferences.

Also - you wont be able to access a webcam on MacOS. There is no direct USB (serial) access to the video feed and it would require entitlements that requires a `MacOS App` project, not a `command line tool`.

Comment: So how can i solve it ? Just tried now to append the flag as you said but still got the same error. If you can guide me , maybe I should try it on Clion or Vscode it will be easier ? I don’t know why it so complicated compared to python 

Comment: Python is written in C/C++. You should read a book about getting started with C++. If you're developing on Mac you will need to learn Swift if you want hardware access like Webcams.